# CronJob is not execute my Laravel application scheduled functions I setup on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, cron

my crontab script

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/{project_folder}/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

projectfolder>app>console>kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('appointment:get')
                 ->everyMinute(); 
    }
```

I set this above crontab script to run every minutes. But it's not run.

Comment: run command 'php /var/www/html/{project_folder}/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1' on your command line and chek if its working independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra "1" in your cron schedule. It should be

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/{project_folder}/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`